# error with ruby module and classes

Tags: ruby, module

I want to make a Ruby package to be available on the rubygems.org but my problem is in the file where I want to write the actual code, I'm confused. I watched some tutorials and saw something like this:

suppose the folder is

```
Mygem
  |__ lib
      |__ Mygem
         |__ Mygem.rb
         |__ version.rb
```

Inside the mygem.rb is the code:

```
class Sample
  "all codes"
end

module Somemodule
  class Someclass
  "somecodes"
  end

  def add(a,b)
    a+b
  end
end
```

Which of the two codes are necessary in the package and how can an instance of the module be called. Say for example I want to use the add method of the module.

I tried doing:

```
Somemodule::add.new(5,7)
```

but I get a undefined method 'add' for Somemodule:Module (nomethod error.)

---

I managed to get it working by adding changing add to **self.add** and methods should not have a **.new** I guess. maybe for only classes. AND I also tried Mymodule.add(4,7) and it worked.

Comment: Please where in the tree would it be required because I tried using a class and it worked fine but i dont understand why it didnt work for the mehod and im still testing them in the same file so i think requiring it is not really needed

Comment: What do you think `Somemodule::add.new` does and what should it do?

Comment: @cremno i think it creates an instance of the add method of the Somemodule module

Answer (score 1):

`Somemodule#add` is an instance method of the module, which means that you can only invoke it on an instance of a class that has [Module#include](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-include)ed the module or on a module (including classes) that has [Object#extend](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Object.html#method-i-extend)ed the module (invoked, in the latter case, `MyMod.add(5,7)` or `MyClass.add(5,7)`).

To use `add` as a module method (sometimes called a module "function"), you must define `self.add` in the module  (or `extend` the module on itself--see below). A module method `m` of module `M` is invoked `M.m`, not `M::m`. `::` is used to reference classes and modules within `M`. `include M` and `extend M` disregard `M`'s module methods (if it has any).

Lastly, `add` has nothing to do with the classes `Sample` and `Somemodule::Someclass`, so it boils down to this:

```
module Somemodule
  def self.add(a,b)
    a+b
  end
end

Somemodule.methods(false)          #=> [:add]     
Somemodule.instance_methods(false) #=> []     
Somemodule.add(5,7)                #=>12
```

As I metioned above, you could alternatively write:

```
module Somemodule
  def add(a,b)
    a+b
  end
  extend(self)
end
```

to create both a module and instance method `:add`:

```
Somemodule.instance_methods(false) #=> [:add]     
Somemodule.methods(false)          #=> []
Somemodule.methods.include?(:add)  #=> true     
Somemodule.method(:add).owner      #=> Somemodule
Somemodule.add(5,7)                #=> 12
```

Here `extend` could instead be invoked after the module has been defined:

```
module Somemodule
  def add(a,b)
    a+b
  end
end

Somemodule.extend(Somemodule)

Somemodule.instance_methods(false) #=> [:add]     
Somemodule.methods.include?(:add)  #=> true     
Somemodule.add(5,7)                #=>12
```

Comment: Thanks this is more explanatory.